# Laravel 8 custom headers run only for home page

Tags: php, laravel, http, header

I want to add custom headers for every response from my Laravel project.

I created a middleware using
`php artisan make:middleware customheaders`
then I used this code in `customheaders` middleware

```php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);
    $response->header('X-CUSTOM-HEADER', 'myCustomHeader');
    return $response;
}
```

then I added my class to kernel

```php
    protected $middleware = [
        ...
        \App\Http\Middleware\customheaders::class,
    ];
```

Now if I run my application home page `localhost:8000` I can see my custom headers but if I go to any other page like `localhost:8000/dashboard` I can't see my custom headers.

There are no any errors that appears, also no errors on the logs.

So what's wrong?

Comment: How have you defined your routes?

Comment: Share a code snippet

Comment: You have to pass each route through this customheaders middleware

Comment: Or make it global

Comment: Isn't `protected $middleware[]` global already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching I can't figure a way to do it with Laravel.
I tried to add my custom middleware to global middlewares. 
Also tried to pass each route through the middleware. 
But always the same result, The headers are showen only at home page only.\

So I did it by the old way
I edited `public/index.php` file and added `header()` at the top of the file and it worked perfectly.